# Spot Light seems to always point to the center of the world

Tags: xna, shader, monogame, hlsl, lighting

I'm currently facing the problem, that my spot light seems to always face the center of my world even though I double checked the direction vector I'm passing to the shader.

Point lights with the same code (but without limiting the light based on its allowed angle and direction) work fine. So my light vector and everything seems to work.

Here a picture of this behavior:

[image]

On the picture the light is facing upwards to the center of the world instead of to the right where the drone is facing. The blue point light is there to demonstrate that lighting otherwise seems to work.

I'm calculating my lights in view space and pass the following to the shader:

```
SpotLightPositionViewSpace[spotLightNum] = Vector3.Transform(l.getPosition(), viewMatrix);
…
SpotLightDirectionViewSpace[spotLightNum] = Vector3.Normalize(Vector3.Transform(l.getLightDirection(), viewMatrix));
SpotLightAngleCos[spotLightNum] = (float)Math.Cos((double)(l.getLightAngleRad() / 2f));
```

In the shader I don't light the pixel if the dot product between the light direction and the light vector is larger than the cosine of the maximum allowed angle of the light (will do this more smoothly as soon as it works):

```
lightDirection = normalize(SpotLightPositionViewSpace[j] - pin.PositionViewSpace.xyz);

if (intensityBasedOnDistance > 0.0 
&& (intensity = max(dot(surfaceNormal, lightDirection), 0.0)) > 0.0 
&& dot(-lightDirection, SpotLightDirectionViewSpace[j]) > SpotLightAngleCos[j])
{
diffuseColor += float4(SpotLightColor[j] * intensity * intensityBasedOnDistance * SpotLightIntensity[j], 0.0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying for hours changing

```
SpotLightDirectionViewSpace[spotLightNum] = Vector3.Normalize(Vector3.Transform(l.getLightDirection(), viewMatrix));
```

to

```
SpotLightDirectionViewSpace[spotLightNum] = Vector3.Normalize(Vector3.Transform(l.getForward(), viewMatrix.Rotation));
```

solved it ... No idea why but it works now.

If someone could explain this I would be very grateful.